# How do I modify a container while iterating over it?

Tags: rust, iteration

I'm referring to the container itself, not the contents of the container.  I want to insert, remove, append, etc. I made an abstraction of my problem below:

```
fn f() {
    let mut numbers = vec![10, 11, 12, 14, 15];

    for index in 0..numbers.len() {
        process(numbers[index]);

        if numbers[index] == 12 {
            numbers.insert(index + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Function `f` would work, but the number of times it loops over the container does not change as the size of the container changes.

```
fn g() {
    let mut numbers = vec![10, 11, 12, 14, 15];

    for (index, num) in numbers.iter().enumerate() {
        process(num);

        if num == 12 {
            numbers.insert(index + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Function `g` looks like the most idiomatic Rust way to do this, but it does not compile due to an illegal mutable borrow references occurring.

```
fn h() {
    let mut numbers = vec![10, 11, 12, 14, 15];

    let mut index = 0;
    while index < numbers.len() {
        process(numbers[index]);

        if numbers[index] == 12 {
            numbers.insert(index + 1);
        }

        index += 1;
    }
}
```

Function `h` is the only version that works but it does not seem like the right way to do it. I'm basically just simulating a C style `for` loop with a `while` loop. I'm hoping someone knows of a more succinct way of writing it, preferably with a `for` loop instead.

Comment: Changing a collection while you are iterating over it is generally a bad idea. Rust's collection iterators give you references to items to be maximally efficient. If you removed or added a value, that could invalidate the reference you were holding, leading to memory unsafety. Removing could also cause you to "miss" an element. Using an index and the while loop is a correct solution, although I like to push to a temporary vector, myself.

Comment: @Shepmaster It looks like most of the questions you marked mine a duplicate of are in fact different questions with answers that are incompatible with my question. Really only the second question contained an relevant answer which was almost an exact copy of my last example which does not help me at all.

Comment: *only the second question contained an relevant answer which was almost an exact copy of my last example* — that's because your last example *is* how you'd do it, when you really truly need to. All the others are addressing the general title you have about modifying an arbitrary collection in an arbitrary fashion, and are there for everyone else who will find your question through whatever path.

Comment: Fair enough on the point of those questions being useful to others. I'm still a little disappointed that the C/C++ solution to this is cleaner than the Rust solution though.

Comment: *C/C++ solution to this is cleaner* — that may be, but it's also less safe. For example, in your `g` function, if the vector needed to reallocate to accommodate the new value, `num` would no longer point to a valid piece of memory. Accessing it could lead to arbitrary code execution, segfaults, etc. Rust has chosen to make the safer cases efficient by default and the other cases not so. For example, your function *copies* the value in the iterator out of the vector on every index — therefore no reference to the vector is needed. If your item was huge, you'd pay the cost.

Comment: You may find enlightening [this list of functions that may invalidate `std::vector` iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector#Iterator_invalidation).