# Complex vector manipulation during iteration

Tags: vector, rust, iteration, borrow-checker

I have a struct `GameLog` that holds a `Vec<Steps>`. `Steps` holds a `Vec<FieldData>` and `FieldData` consists only of basic data types.

I create instances of these types using serde_json. After the deserialisation is done, I need to iterate over all the steps in the `GameData` and add to it the past version of the fields that are changed in the next turn it doesn't already contain.

I have a working Java implementation I'm trying to port to Rust, but I just can't figure this out, probably because I  don't know enough about Rust's insides.

The current code looks like this:

```
let data = load_data("Path/to/json");
let mut gamelog: Vec<Vec<FieldData>> = Vec::with_capacity(data.steps.len() + 1);
gamelog.push(Vec::with_capacity(data.init.fields.len()));
gamelog[0] = data.init.fields;
for i in 1..(data.steps.len() - 1) {
    gamelog.push(Vec::with_capacity(data.steps[i - 1].fields.len()));
    gamelog[i] = data.steps[i - 1].fields.clone();
    for future_field in &data.steps[i + 1].fields {
        let mut inside = false;
        for current_field in &data.steps[i].fields {
            if current_field.x == future_field.x && current_field.y == future_field.y {
                inside = true;
            }
        }
        if !inside {
            for j in i..0 {
                let mut insideb = false;
                for past_field in &data.steps[j].fields {
                    if future_field.x == past_field.x && future_field.y == past_field.y {
                        gamelog[i].push(past_field.clone());
                        insideb = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if insideb {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, this only works by creating copies of the vectors and fields and creates a new `Vec`.
When I try to manipulate the `Vec` directly, I most often get a "can't move out of borrow" error on the `for .. in data.steps[?].fields` lines

What would a proper (and possibly much more idiomatic) way of directly manipulating the `Vec`s in the struct?

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. We cannot tell what crates, types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. Make it **minimal** — does the question really need 3 nested data types when 2 or one would show the problem equally well? Try to produce something that reproduces your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) or you can reproduce it in a brand new Cargo project. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) as well.

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [Efficiently mutate a vector while also iterating over the same vector](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49143770/155423); [Is there an elegant solution to modifying a structure while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29322932/155423); [How do I modify a container while iterating over it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47338839/155423) and **many more**. If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.