# Mutate a field of a Vec's element while looping over a field of another element in the same Vec

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm writing a Trie data structure in Rust to implement the Aho-Corasick algorithm. The `TrieNode` struct respresents a node and looks like this:

```
use std::collections::{HashMap, HashSet, VecDeque};

struct TrieNode {
    next_ids: HashMap<char, usize>,
    kw_indices: HashSet<usize>,
    fail_id: Option<usize>,
}
```

I use the same strategy as a generational arena to implement the trie, where all the nodes are stored in one `Vec` and reference each other using their indices. When building the automaton after creating the all the nodes, I'm trying to get the following code work without using the `clone()` method:

```
fn build_ac_automaton(nodes: &mut Vec<TrieNode>) {
    let mut q = VecDeque::new();
    for &i in nodes[0].next_ids.values() {
        q.push_back(i);
        nodes[i].fail_id = Some(0);
    }
    // ...
}
```

but the borrow checker is not very happy about it:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*nodes` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
   |
   |             for &i in nodes[0].next_ids.values() {
   |                       -----                    - immutable borrow ends here
   |                       |
   |                       immutable borrow occurs here
   |                 q.push_back(i);
   |                 nodes[i].fail_id = Some(0);
   |                 ^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
```

What is another way (if any) to achieve the above without using the costly `clone()` method?

Comment: The existing [aho-corasick](https://crates.io/crates/aho-corasick) crate.

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [Efficiently mutate a vector while also iterating over the same vector](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49143770/155423); [Is there an elegant solution to modifying a structure while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29322932/155423); [How do I modify a container while iterating over it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47338839/155423) and **many more**. If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Answer (score 5):

Split the slice:

```
fn build_ac_automaton(nodes: &mut Vec<TrieNode>) {
    let mut q = VecDeque::new();
    let (first, rest) = nodes.split_first_mut();
    for &i in first.next_ids.values() {
        q.push_back(i);
        if i == 0 {
            first.fail_id = Some(0);
        } else {
            rest[i-1].fail_id = Some(0);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

However it might be less costly to simply clone only the `next_ids`:

```
fn build_ac_automaton(nodes: &mut Vec<TrieNode>) {
    let mut q = VecDeque::new();
    let ids: Vec<_> = nodes[0].next_ids.values().cloned().collect();
    for &i in ids {
        q.push_back(i);
        nodes[i].fail_id = Some(0);
    }
    ...
}
```